# Why on GUI the shutdown is rootless whilst on terminal is not?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, root, gui

In older days that I used to run Fluxbox, in order to be able to shutdown my computer I need to allow passwordless root access via `sudo` to the command 
`shutdown` by running `viedit` and doing the appropriate changes.

Also when the computer shutdown my computer is perfmormed over terminal via the `shutdown` command, root access is needed.

But modern Desktop GUI implementations such as KDE/GNOME/LXDE/XFCE etc etc the shutdown is by default rootless (no root password is required). And I wonder how theese desktop GUIS manage to "perform"/notify the kernel that the computer is shutting down without the need of root access?

Comment: There is a deamon running as root that exposes itself on DBus and receives requests from clients, for example `upowerd`. Also `policykit` plays a role here but I don't use Ubuntu on the daily bases and I know systemd replaced consolekit for example.